# Can't modify or add contact types

Tags: contact-types, formbuilder

I have found an error when want to display the page Contact Types. The page is empty. I can't access to the types and subtypes. I opened the page in form builder - edit form but it can't modify the form. I can see the the Form Setting but don't the part where I can modify the fields.
This CiviCRM is on wordpress, updated to the last version 5.54.1 Italian Translation
[image]

Comment: Does it work if you disable the AdminUI extension?

Comment: Thank you much @LarsSG, uninstalling AdminUI works.

Comment: That's good to hear. I just tried it on the Wordpress demo site (5.57) and it seems to be working properly, even in Italian. So hopefully it will be fixed when you upgrade to 5.55 or later. If not, maybe create a Github issue.